# Distributed File System (DFS) and MS SQL 2008

Tags: sql-server, dfs, distributed-filesystems

There are two physical servers on which we want to install MS SQL 2008 and our application. Our application is using DB in separate *.mdf file.  Our application works only on one server at the point of time.

Can we create this file (*.mdf) on the DFS? Will this file be the same if we start our application on second server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Two servers can't access the same file simulaneously
- SQL Server doesn't allow databases on network shares

If the DFS is a "local disk" to the server than you may be able to use DFS. However, you can't have a 2nd SQL Server using it.

Typically, you'd have one SQL Server with several clients (weg a web farm) connecting to it.

If you ask because unless you have some serious reporting requirements on a busy server, just have one SQL box.

If you want this for DR purposes, then look at [database mirroring](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc917680.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for answer. What do you mean "local disk"? We have disk array connected by SAS to both servers. We want to be able to start our application with the same data if first server will go down.

Comment: local means it appears in "Computer management". If you want this failover, then look at clustering.

Comment: Thanks... But I don`t know is it possible to use clustering when DB and application are on the same servers...

Answer (score 0):

There is a lengthy discussion on using file servers as the storage for SQL databases in [KB304261](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304261/en-us). The bottom line is: don't do it unless you know **exactly** what you are doing.